# Loop through pair of files python

Tags: python

I have a script that receives two files as input and creates a dictionary based on lines. Finally, it overwrites the first file.

I am looking for a way to run this script on all file pairs of a folder, choosing as sys.argv[1] and sys.argv[2] based on a pattern in the name.

```
import re
import sys

datafile = sys.argv[1]
schemaseqs = sys.argv[2]

datafile_lines = []
d = {}
prev = None
with open(datafile, 'r') as f:
    i = 0
    for line in f:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            d[line.strip()]=0
            prev = line.strip()
        else:
            d[prev] = line.strip()
        i+=1

new_d = {}
with open(schemaseqs, 'r') as f:
    i=0
    prev = None
    for line in f:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            new_d[line.strip()]=0
            prev = line.strip()
        else:
            new_d[prev] = line.strip()
        i+=1

for key, value in d.items():
    if value in new_d:
        d[key] = new_d[value]

print(d)

with open(datafile,'w') as filee:
    for k,v in d.items():
        filee.writelines(k)
        filee.writelines('\n')
        filee.writelines(v)
        filee.writelines('\n')
```

I have hundreds of file pairs all sharing the same pattern proteinXXXX (where XXXX is a number) This number can have up to four digits (e.g. 9,99,999 or 9999). So I have protein 555.txt and protein 555.fasta

I've seen I can use glob or os.listdir to read files from a directory. However, I cannot assign them to a variable and extract the lines one pair at a time in every pair of the directory.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you reading files from single folder or multiple folders?

Comment: From two different folders, but I can join into one

Answer (score 2):

Just the concept.

Import required libraries.

```py
import glob
import os.path
```

Define function that extracts only the *basename* (the part without extension) from filename.

```py
def basename(fn):
    return os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(fn))[0]
```

Create two sets, one with `.txt` files, another with `.fasta` files.

```py
t = {basename(fn) for fn in glob.glob("protein*.txt")}
f = {basename(fn) for fn in glob.glob("protein*.fasta")}
```

Calculate intersection of these two sets to be sure that both `.txt` and `.fasta` files exist with the same *basename*. Then add the missing suffixes and let them process with the existing code.

```py
for bn in t.intersection(f):
    process(bn + ".txt", bn + ".fasta")
```